# Trying to understand a peculiar TeX document format

Tags: tikz-pgf, typography

I often surf [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/) for new articles to read. I usually benefit doubly from this endeavour: secondly to mathematical knowledge I like to learn different LaTeX techniques which are used to typeset beautiful documents. But recently I got a hold of rather peculiar `.tex` file. Its origins derive from a brilliant article regarding algebraic topology which can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/format/1509.06811).

The whole file is way too large to be rawly posted in my comment, so I included it in my Google Drive. However I *can* express two of my remarks:

It seems strange to me that multiple `.sty` files were packed in a single `.tex` file, as recognised via Google Drive analysis; more accurately, it seems that 8 individual files (1 `.aux`, 1 `.bbl`, 3 `.sty` and 3 `.tex`) are somehow compressed in one `.tex` file. Strange.

I decided to post the beginning of the "big" `.tex` document for further clarity and to make the situation simpler for the community:

```
                              \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{Cobordism}[2011/03/01]

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\usepackage{forarray}

\newcommand\ignore[1]{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  Variables, Variable Commands, and Styles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%% Variables %%%
\newlength{\cobordismhalfendwidth}
\newlength{\cobordismhalfendheight}
\newlength{\cobordismendwidth}

%%% New Variables %%%
\newlength{\cobheight}      % Height of a pair of pants
\newlength{\cobwidth}       % Width of a cylinder
\newlength{\cobgap}         % Gap between adjacent cylinders
\newlength{\cupheight}      % Height of a cup or cap
\newlength{\ellipseheight}  % Height of a boundary ellipse
\newcommand{\ellipsewidth}{\cobwidth}
\newlength{\cobordismlinewidth} % Width of line used to draw cobordisms
\newlength{\coboffset}      % cobwidth + cobgap; the horizontal offset between adjacent cylinders
\newlength{\obscurewidth}
\setlength{\obscurewidth}{4pt}
\newlength{\inseamheight}
\newlength{\selectwidth}
\setlength{\selectwidth}{1pt}
\newlength{\dashlength}
\setlength{\dashlength}{2pt}
```

Those of you who want to help me with my struggle can find the full file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-euccGmliZiVHR6NHBEWWxoV2M).

The ones who took their time and opened my uploaded `.tex` file will probably understand the source of my confusion. **My primary request is to clarify the syntax to me as much as possible.** And a bonus: how can I achieve the beautiful results presented in the paper with the normal format? Thank you in advance. (Please don't mark this as off-topic; it's just a complex question.)

Comment: Is there something in particular you want clarified or the entire thing? I personally don't want to go through thousands of lines of code for that.

Comment: I don't know if it is off-topic, but I don't like questions very much where all relevant information is behind some links. Imho you should make an effort to add at least some example/screenshot here

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I was thinking about adding the first portion of the `.tex` file. Of course, you can download a copy from my Google Drive for yourself (I've provided a link) and see the situation in the upmost clarity. Edit incoming soon.

Comment: (The source can be downloaded from arXiv as well, so not really much need for you posting it to Google Drive.) As it stands though, I'd say your question is either unclear or too broad, or both. There are 8000 lines of code in the paper, so you cannot be expecting a clarification of all of it. Are you referring to the diagrams?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No, I am referring to the structure of the .tex file as well. When you add ".tex" to the name of the source  name (1509.06811) you can edit it with your TeX - LaTeX editor of choice (or even with Notepad++). If you are interested in helping me out, please follow the procedure mentioned above.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. To add, I'd mostly like to know why some of `.sty` and `.bbl` files are so strangely "morphed" with `.tex` packages. If you can shine any light onto as to why such a structure even exist, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: "Delivered as a gzipped tar (.tar.gz) file if there are multiple files," It's not a single text file, it's a zipped file. If you unpack it, instead of renaming, you'll see that it's actually 8 files.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, I was suspecting that I did something wrong (check out my edit). I still don't understand why there are ***3*** `.tex` files though? What am I supposed to do with those?

Comment: Keep them in the folder. Note in line 8 and 9 of `paperIV.tex` that the two other `.tex` files are input here. It's just a way of making the source of the main `.tex` file more tidy, by placing (most of) the preamble in separate files.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks, this clarifies things up a little bit. I know I must move `.sty` files somewhere where PDFLaTeX can reach them and compile my commands. But where? And furthermore, how do I compile 3 `.tex` files at once?

Comment: You don't compile three `.tex` at once, you just compile `paperIV.tex`. That file reads the two other ones. And you don't need to move the `.sty` files either, if they are placed in the same folder as `paperIV.tex`, LaTeX will find them.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks a lot man! It's a shame that you didn't post this as an answer. You would indeed get my tick and an upvote...

Comment: Well, to answer a question you first need to understand the problem ... I can summarize my comments in an answer later.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That would be great! Keep up the good work!

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Um, another question. I tried compiling `paperIV.tex`. All was well (you know, the standard stuff; editor automatically installs requested packages etc.) until this error showed up: `Cobordism.sty   error   line 4118   undefined control sequence`. I suspect that the `.sty` file has some kind of fallacy in it (is not written correctly). Your thoughts?

Comment: Not much. Possibly written for an older version of TikZ, but I'd suggest asking a new question about that, I don't really know.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Did the `.tex` file compile for you though?

Comment: No, same error.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: I already said I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

arXiv says this about the source:

> **Source**
>
> Delivered as a gzipped tar (.tar.gz) file if there are multiple files, otherwise as a PDF file, or a gzipped TeX, DVI, PostScript or HTML (.gz, .dvi.gz, .ps.gz or .html.gz) file depending on submission format.

And indeed, my terminal tells me this:

```
$ file 1509.06811 
1509.06811: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

Hence, you cannot just rename the file, you need to unpack/extract it. Exact details for that will depend on the system, in Kubuntu I can just right click the file and choose Extract.

After extracting, you'll see that there are eight different files:

```
$ ls
Cobordism.sty  knots.sty    paperIV.bbl  spath.sty
header.tex     paperII.aux  paperIV.tex  stringdiagram-header.tex
```

The file `paperIV.tex` is the main article file. The other two `.tex` files contain the bulk of the preamble for `paperIV.tex`, and are included in lines 8-9 of that:

```
7 % Import the preamble
8 \include{header}
9 \include{stringdiagram-header}
```

(The numbers indicate line numbers. Note that in the preamble one should use `\input`, not `\include`, see [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include))

Hence, the two other `.tex` files should not be compiled, the reason for having them is to make the preamble of the "main" file more tidy. You could have replaced line 8 and 9 in `paperIV.tex` with the 700+ lines of code from those files and the result would be the same.

To make a PDF you should in theory just be able to do `pdflatex paperIV.tex`, but unfortunately that throws an error in `Cobordism.sty`:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\anchor ... \csname pgf@anchor@\pgf@sm@shape@name 
                                                  @#1\endcsname {#2}
l.4118 }
```

I don't know exactly why that occurs, possibly `Cobordism.sty` was written for TikZ 2.x, and needs some updating for use with TikZ 3. That is just a wild stab in the dark though, I'd suggest asking a new question about that specific problem.

LaTeX will always look in the current folder for packages, so you don't have to move the `.sty` files anywhere else, but for reference: [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te)

Note however a couple of things:

- There is a newer version of `spath`, called `spath3`, already on CTAN, and in TeXLive/MikTeX.
- You might be interested in the `tqft` package, see e.g. [drawing cobordisms using tqft](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312405/drawing-cobordisms-using-tqft)