# Seemingly universal error regarding Cobordism.sty

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

When trying to compile a `.tex` document which required a `.sty` file named `Cobordism.sty` a strange error arised:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\anchor ... \csname pgf@anchor@\pgf@sm@shape@name 
@#1\endcsname {#2}
l.4118 }

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Or for short:

```
Cobordism.sty   error   line 4118   Undefined control sequence. }
```

At first I though this error was due to my insufficient setup, but then another user Torbjørn T. kindly re-tested my attempt - the same exact error occured. I think it would be too bold to suggest that the `.sty` file itself has a coding error. As Torbjørn T. suggested in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383592/trying-to-understand-a-peculiar-tex-document-format/383619#383619) answer to my previous problem the crux is probably in the compatibility (maybe `Cobordism.sty` is a predecessor to a newer package like for example `tqft.sty`).

To make things easier for the ones who are interested in helping I posted the whole file (all of the components necessary for compilation, *including* `Cobordism.sty`) [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-euccGmliZiZ2tqV2JJbkFZdm8) (in the `.rar` format).

**DISCLAIMER: BE WELL AWARE THAT THE FILE DISTRIBUTED WAS DOWNLOADED AS A SOURCE FILE FROM ARXIV. VIA ARXIV POLICIES THIS FALLS UNDER THE FAIR USE. ALL OF THE CREDIT BELONGS TO THE ORIGINAL AUTHORS.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The style has an error. It uses internal pgf commands but has not adapted them to newer pgf codes. So it works in texlive 2012 but breaks with later version.

There is no possibility to adapt it outside the style. You will have to make a copy and change in line 4046 this here:

```
\def\pgfaddtoshape#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \def\shape@name{#1}% 
  \def\pgf@sm@shape@name{#1}%new 
  \let\anchor\pgf@sh@anchor
  #2%
  \endgroup
}
```

Comment: Could one `\xpatchcmd`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes No the definition is directly before the use.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you so much! It works perfectly! A big tick and an upvote from my side are well deserved, sir!

Comment: @GregorPerčič not Sir, but Madam

Comment: @jfbu It's just a phrase. You don't often hear: "Well said, madam." And yes, I am well aware that "Ulrike" is a feminine German name.

Comment: @GregorPerčič It is not "just" a phrase. This sort of phrase hides women.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just wanted to point out that it is a common phrase. I have nothing against women, nor do I think they are less capable than men and that they don't deserve *just as much* recognition as them. I am thankful for your answer, no matter your gender. Please refrain from turning this into an unpleasant gender crusade. The fact is that in the English language the male-oriented phrases are more common and that will not stop people from using them. I'm disgusted by sexism towards either of genders and by that I stand. Cheers.

Comment: I prefer not to be called "Sir" as I'm not a Sir. Common phrases can change, they did in Germany and I'm certain they can also in countries who speak english.